# How to handle partial success when returning multiple resources in REST

Tags: rest

What is the design guideline for handling partial success when fetching multiple resources using HTTP GET in REST API?

Assume that I have 10 customers with 5 having membership status as "active" and 5 having the status as "verification in progress"

My use case is to return all customer records

HTTP GET /customers should return 10 records.

However in this case for 5 customers since the membership status is pending, I would not return all the details for them. Instead I shall return only basic details (id, name) while for the remaining 5 customers whose membership status is "active" I shall return the full details

Seen from this perspective, it is a partial success

For this condition, is it acceptable to return HTTP 207 and have an error code associated with each customer record as well?

Is there a mandate that each customer record itself must have a HTTP status code associated with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can check http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html for a resource on REST status codes. Specifically,

> 206 Partial Content

The important part is the response include:

> Either a Content-Range header field (section 14.16) indicating the
>   range included with this response, or a multipart/byteranges
>   Content-Type including Content-Range fields for each part. If a
>   Content-Length header field is present in the response, its value MUST
>   match the actual number of OCTETs transmitted in the message-body.

So the response must explicitly say what what content was successfully returned.`207` indicates a mutli-status response, which is more general and usually less indicative. The official site for this is http://www.ietf.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml if you want something more formal.